# TSL2591 sensor value calculation

Tags: i2c, physics, documentation, light-sensor

I bought an TSL2591 breakout board and wanted to write driver for my board.

After looking at the documentation, i found that i cannot calculate the illuminance value (in Lux) as their was algorithm not given.

I tried the Adafruit TSL2591 Arduino code but no description.
I tried for App note on how to use the device or some physics description, Nothing.
I also tried Adafruit forum (no acceptable answer  ~2 days) and emailing AMS (no reply   ~ 2 days).

```
uint32_t Adafruit_TSL2591::calculateLux(uint16_t ch0, uint16_t ch1)
{
  uint16_t atime, again;
  float    cpl, lux1, lux2, lux;
  uint32_t chan0, chan1;

  // Check for overflow conditions first
  if ((ch0 == 0xFFFF) | (ch1 == 0xFFFF))
  {
    // Signal an overflow
    return 0;
  }

  // Note: This algorithm is based on preliminary coefficients
  // provided by AMS and may need to be updated in the future

  switch (_integration)
  {
    case TSL2591_INTEGRATIONTIME_100MS :
      atime = 100.0F;
      break;
    case TSL2591_INTEGRATIONTIME_200MS :
      atime = 200.0F;
      break;
    case TSL2591_INTEGRATIONTIME_300MS :
      atime = 300.0F;
      break;
    case TSL2591_INTEGRATIONTIME_400MS :
      atime = 400.0F;
      break;
    case TSL2591_INTEGRATIONTIME_500MS :
      atime = 500.0F;
      break;
    case TSL2591_INTEGRATIONTIME_600MS :
      atime = 600.0F;
      break;
    default: // 100ms
      atime = 100.0F;
      break;
  }

  switch (_gain)
  {
    case TSL2591_GAIN_LOW :
      again = 1.0F;
      break;
    case TSL2591_GAIN_MED :
      again = 25.0F;
      break;
    case TSL2591_GAIN_HIGH :
      again = 428.0F;
      break;
    case TSL2591_GAIN_MAX :
      again = 9876.0F;
      break;
    default:
      again = 1.0F;
      break;
  }

  // cpl = (ATIME * AGAIN) / DF
  cpl = (atime * again) / TSL2591_LUX_DF;

  lux1 = ( (float)ch0 - (TSL2591_LUX_COEFB * (float)ch1) ) / cpl;
  lux2 = ( ( TSL2591_LUX_COEFC * (float)ch0 ) - ( TSL2591_LUX_COEFD * (float)ch1 ) ) / cpl;

  // The highest value is the approximate lux equivalent
  lux = lux1 > lux2 ? lux1 : lux2;

  // Signal I2C had no errors
  return (uint32_t)lux;
}
```

query is:

- what is "cpl"
- why calculating cpl (though, related to above)
- what is "TSL2591_LUX_DF"
- what is "lux1", "lux2"    (is related to infrared? and visible?).
- why the comparision between "lux1", "lux2"

any pointers of algorithm or the actual physics behind the calculation would be helpful (i would love to read/know the physics behind the sensor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sensor has two integrating light sensors with different wavelength responses.  The purpose for this setup is to allow the sensor to simulate the spectral response of the human eye.  The first chart below is the human eye's response, the second is the response from the sensor datasheet.  The calculation at the end with the coefficients is to convert the sensor outputs to lux.  Lux is lumens per m^2, and a lumen is defined according to the response of the human eye.

[image: Human eye spectral response]

[image: TSL2591]

cpl - 
The general idea is that you set the gain for the input, then set the amount of time the sensor collects light. The longer time you select, the more light you will get.  Once this is complete this, you will have a certain number of ADC counts.  This has to be scaled by that gain and integration time. cpl appears to be that "counts per lux" scaling.

TSL2691_LUX_DF - This is hard to say for certain given the information, but it appears to simply be the default lux per count given a gain of 1 and an integration time of 1 ms.

If you want more info about the sensor, go to the AMS website and find white papers there.  They are under the sensors themselves.

For radiometric physics, the Georgia State University Hyperphysics resources are fantastic:  http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/ligcon.html#c1

Comment: Oh, their is docs below. No Script seems to be the reason. without allowing for google.com, it don't show tables and links.

Comment: loading "https://www.google.com/jsapi", and `google.load("jquery", "1.7.1");` -> loading jquery. google can now track me :(  | lol "alert(e);" in production server. :p